# Can't find the Web scraping selector for div class

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am new to Web scraping and this is one of my first web scraping project, I cant find the right selector for my `soup.select("")`

I want to get the "data-phone" (See picture bellow to undersdtand) But it In a div class and after it in a `<a href>`, who make that a little complicate for me!

I searched online and I foud that I have to use soup.find_all but this is not very helpfull Can anyone help me or give me a quick tip ?Thanks you!

my code:

```
import webbrowser, requests, bs4, os

url = "https://www.pagesjaunes.ca/search/si/1/electricien/Montreal+QC"
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)


result = soup.find('a', {'class', 'mlr__item__cta jsMlrMenu'})
Phone = result['data-phone']
print(Phone)
```

[image]

Comment: You want to get the phone number only from the first anchor or from all the anchors available in that unordered list (<u>)?

Comment: @V.Sambor from all the anchors

Comment: I don't see the others anchor classes, but you could try something like this: `a.mlr__item_cta.jsMlrMenu` as selector

Comment: It gave me a empty list, lets say I only want the first anchor, it doesnt matter honestly

Comment: BeautifulSoup can't run JavaScript - so first check if page doesn't use JavaScript to add items - turn off JavaScript in browser and load page again.

Comment: you should add url to this page so we could see it and test it with some code.

Comment: @tiberhockey have update the answer. Please check it out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the simplest way is to use the `soup.select` which allows the normal css selectors.
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors

```
soup.select('a.mlr__item_cta.jsMlrMenu')
```

This should return the entire list of anchors from which you can pick the data attribute.

Note I just tried it in the terminal:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping'
r  = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

result = soup.select('a.mw-jump-link') # or any other selector

print(result)

print(result[0].get("href"))
```

You will have to loop over the result of `soup.select` and just collect the `data-phone` value from the attribute.

#### UPDATE

Ok I have searched in the `DOM` myself, and here is how I managed to retrieve all the phone data:

```
anchores = soup.select('a[data-phone]') 
    for a in anchores:
        print(a.get('data-phone'))
```

It works also with only data selector like this: `soup.select('[data-phone]')`

Here real proof: 
[image]

Surprisingly, for me it works also this one with classes:

```
for a in soup.select('a.mlr__item__cta.jsMlrMenu'):
     print(a.get('data-phone'))
```

There is no surprise, we just had a typo in our first selector... 
Find the difference :)

GOOD: `a.mlr__item__cta.jsMlrMenu`
BAD :   `a.mlr__item_cta.jsMlrMenu`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried it whith the ```soup.select('a.mlr__item_cta.jsMlrMenu')``` but it give me an empty list ```[]```

Comment: Then try just `soup.select('a')` to be sure that it returns something...then if it works, you can try with one class `soup.select('a.mlr__item_cta')` or you can even try just by class  `soup.select('mlr__item_cta')`... let me know how does it goes.

Comment: When I try ```soup.select('a')``` it return something but when I try ```soup.select('a.mlr__item_cta') ``` or ```soup.select('mlr__item_cta')``` it return nothing, I eddited my post so you can see my code..

Comment: There shuld be a dot before the class `soup.select('.mlr__item_cta')` try now

Comment: Still an empty list

Comment: ok then you'd have to include the `DOM` in your question so that we can test on ourself ;)  (bacause it's completly strange that it does not find by class)

Comment: And maybe is a good idea to tell use which version of soup you are using...

Comment: Thanks you for your help and time, I use the lastest bs4 version 4.8.2 on Pycharm. I dont know what ```DOM``` mean, but Im trying to scrapt then all the "telephone" data on the page. The url is On my code

Comment: Ahhh, I haven't seen you put the link in your question. I will check tonight and come back to you (no need for other info)

Comment: @tiberhockey I have added the new response, please check it out.

Comment: awesome it working and I understand the logic behind! thank you!